# Display records by comparing with session email and table email id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to fetch only records from table by comparing it with session email id and table email id
I tried following Code
Controller

```
public function employer_dashboard(){
        $result['jobs'] = $this->Employer_model->fetch_postedJobs();
        $this->load->view('employer/header');
        $this->load->view('employer/employer_dashboard',$result);
        $this->load->view('employer/footer');
    }
```

Model

```
function fetch_postedJobs() {
        $this->db->select('job_title,vacancies,exp_required,salary');
        $this->db->from('tbl_postjob');
        $this->db->where('contact_email', trim($_SESSION['employer_email']));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
   }
```

View

```
<tbody id="filter-data">
                            <?php $i=1; foreach($jobs as $data){ ?>
                                <tr>

                                    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $data->job_title;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $data->vacancies?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $data->exp_required?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $data->salary?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php $i++; } ?>
                                </tbody>
```

It shows error as Undefined variable:

jobs and warning as Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I am accessing all session data as

```
$this->session->set_userdata('employer_email', $result[0]->employer_email);
```

I can access this using 
`<?php echo $_SESSION['employer_email'];?>`

Comment: In the method `fetch_postedJobs()`, you never return `$result`. In fact, you're not returning anything at all, which would make `$result['jobs']` to contain `null` (which is an invalid value for foreach)

Comment: where is your `return $result;` statement?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am new in php codeignitor can u please help me how to add that code as i did return $result->result(); also i tried return $result; in both case i got the same error

Comment: @M.Hemant I tried `return $result;` but it still shows same error

Comment: This has nothing to do with codeigniter. This is basic PHP (or even basic programming in many many languages). If you want a function/method to return a value, you must use [return](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Comment: Then show what you have. I can't help debug code I can't see. Also, the view you've posted, is that the `employer_dashboard` view or is it some other view or partial (view loaded inside another view)? You can also do `var_dump($result);` in your controller method to see if it contains what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please check session `employer_email` with `echo die` method and try below code

Model:

```
function fetch_postedJobs() {
        $this->db->select('job_title,vacancies,exp_required,salary');
        $this->db->from('tbl_postjob');
        $this->db->where('contact_email', trim($_SESSION['employer_email']));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
   }
```

Controller:

```
public function employer_dashboard(){
        $result = array();
        $result['jobs'] = $this->Employer_model->fetch_postedJobs();
        echo '<pre>';print_r($result);die;
        $this->load->view('employer/header');
        $this->load->view('employer/employer_dashboard',$result);
        $this->load->view('employer/footer');
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand why it is showing the same error as i have changed code as u provided .

Comment: Are you getting an email in the session? and according to my code, you supposed to see your DB data as an array, it won't go in view

Comment: yes after login i have set all the session data and also i can access that data

Comment: try this,`echo $this->db->last_query();die;` in the model after your `$query = $this->db->get();` line and try that query to your phpmyadmin, Tell me are you getting the data in phpmyadmin

Comment: can u please provide me ur mail id so that i can explain you

Comment: did you try my last message changes?

Comment: @Sagar - Questions should be asked here, not off-site so please don't ask for other users email so you can continue the question there. Edit your question to include a proper explanation instead

Comment: did you get your expected data in PHPMyAdmin or not from `echo $this->db->last_query();die;`? you didn't tell about it

Comment: @M.Hemant Please check my updated code and i did not get datat from echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: it will `echo $this->db->last_query();die;` give you a query which you need to run in your PHPMyAdmin where you DB is stored so when you run that query you will get data there not in Model

Comment: @M.Hemant Its showing records but problem is sometime it shows  previous error .I think its cache problem or something but ur code works fine Thank you